# Mass upload data to CloudKit?

Tags: ios, database, cloudkit

I have an iOS app that needs to access public data from a database I manage using CloudKit. I have a JSON file with 300+ objects and I need to mass upload it into CloudKit so I can access all of this data in the iOS app. I have done this pretty easily before in Firebase, but don't know if I can do this in CloudKit. I update this JSON file every day (from web scraping) and so I would need to re-upload it to CloudKit frequently. Any workarounds or advice is appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: There is no reason it will not work. It should be very straightforward.

Comment: If it’s straightforward, care to comment on how? I can’t find any information on how to do it. It’s not very clear to be honest.

Comment: Where are you at? Have you defined your records?

Comment: Yes, I created a record type and defined the fields. At this point, I’m just trying to upload a json file that has these fields defined into the database table in CloudKit.